# Using Abel's summation formula, prove f integrable if and only if the sum in n of the measures of the sets with $|f(x)| \geq n$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

The problem staetement is:

Let $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space, and let $f:X \longrightarrow [-\infty,+\infty]$ be a measurable function. Prove that f is integrable if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mu(\lbrace x \in X : |f(x)| \geq  n \rbrace) < \infty$.

Abel's formula: $a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$, let's call $A_k=\sum_{j=1}^{k}a_j$ then $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_kb_k=A_nb_{n+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n}A_k(b_{k+1}-b_k)$.

I will call $f$ like its absolute value, since their integrability is equivalent, just to make the notation  a bit more readable. And also, now f is a nonnegative function, which is good.

I will define some sets at the beginning:

$A_k= \lbrace x \in X : f(x) \geq  n \rbrace$

$B_k= \lbrace x \in X :f(x) \in [k,k+1)\rbrace$. Remark: those are disjoint sets

It's obvious that $X=\cup_{k=0}^{\infty} B_k$, and $A_n=\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}$, so $\mu(X)= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu(B_k)$ and $\mu(A_n) = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \mu(B_k)$

Assume $\sum \mu(A_n) < \infty$, and let's see $f$ is integrable: (I think I have this part okay but please feel free to correct me)

Since $f$ is measurable and bounded in each $B_k$, is integrable in each $B_k$. So:

$\int_X f \,d\mu = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{B_k}fd\mu \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n} (k+1)\mu(B_k)=\mu(X)+\mu(A_1)+\mu(A_2)+... < \infty$ beacuse $\mu$ is finite. This give us $f$ intergable, without using Abel's formula.

Now, my problem. How can I use Abel's formula to show that sum is convergent?, assuming $f$ integrable? I guess it's something like caling $a_k=1$ and $b_k=\mu(A_k)$ but I don't see how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should $\infty$ in the title be $n$?

Comment: whooops yes, i'm editing sorry

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I see now a way to use Abel's summation formula. Set

$$A_n:=n,\quad  b_n:=-\mu(\{x: |f(x)|\geqslant n-1\})\\
\therefore\quad a_n=1,\quad b_{n+1}-b_n=\mu(\{x: n-1\leqslant |f(x)|< n\})$$

then from Abel's formula we have that

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \mu(\{x: |f(x)|\geqslant k-1\})= \sum_{k=1}^n k\,\mu(\{x: k-1\leqslant |f(x)|<k\})+n\,\mu(\{x: |f(x)|\geqslant n\})
$$

Taking limits above we get

$$
\sum_{k\geqslant 1}k\,\mu(\{x:k-1\leqslant |f(x)|<k\})+\lim_{n\to\infty}n\,\mu(\{x: |f(x)|\geqslant n\})<\infty 
$$

As both expressions on the LHS are non-negative we find that

$$
\sum_{k\geqslant 1}k\, \mu(\{x:k-1\leqslant |f(x)|<k\})<\infty 
$$

Finally note that

$$
k\, \mu(\{x:k-1\leqslant |f(x)|<k\})\geqslant \int_{|f|^{-1}([k-1,k))}|f|\,d\mu\quad\text{ for each }k\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}
\\
\therefore\quad \sum_{k\geqslant 1}k\,\mu(\{x:k-1\leqslant |f(x)|<k\})\geqslant \int_{X}|f|\mathop{}\!d \mu
$$

∎